# After installing Ionic I want to build android platform and it is not working

Tags: java, android, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

```
mercy@mercy-DL-H61M-VG3:~/Desktop/todo$ ionic platform add android
The platform command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

  ionic cordova platform --help
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks so much budy

Comment: glad it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

The commands have changed for ionic cli version 3.x

Do:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/platform/) for more.